# Which US states have the most right-wing, "alt-right", KKK affiliated or neo-nazi groups?

Tags: united-states, statistics, alt-right

I've been looking for statistics about the subject, out of personal curiosity.  I know a lot of these groups have no official records, but some do (like militias, etc).  I was wondering if anybody had statistics like the top 10 states with the biggest number of far-right groups.

**EDIT:**

Following the comments I received I'll try to make my question more precise.

By far-right groups, I mean every group that is publicly known as a hate group with or without ties to the KKK and the neo-nazi movement.  I'm not talking about political parties, more about activists groups, self-proclaimed militias and the likes.  Any group promoting white supremacy, hate against other nationalities with a tendency for public demonstrations and violent outbursts.

About the numbers, I realize that I was vague about it and also that population density could bias the numbers so obviously getting a number that would take that into account would be the best (percentage of population involved etc.)

I'm well aware that there is probably no publicly available data that is really reliable because of the "covert" nature of such groups.

Comment: In absolute numbers, or as percentage of population?  Also, a precise definition of "right-wing" would help: do Republicans count?

Comment: @jamesqf : Both numbers are actually interesting to look at.  And as I was talking about right wing "groups" not political parties.  There are only two partirs anyway, why would I consider them anyway?

Comment: Is a political party not a group?  And there are more than two parties in the US: Libertarian, Green, Independent American, and others.  But my question was really about how you go about defining "far right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ABC News](http://www.abc2news.com/news/national/southern-poverty-law-center-lists-active-hate-groups-by-state) has a list of all those organizations designated as a hate group by the SPLC, divided by states. As federal organizations such as the FBI do not keep track of these groups, they are likely the best source you will find for this.

California is currently at the top of their list, Florida is second.

Note that some such as [Fox News](http://www.foxnews.com/us/2017/08/18/california-is-no-1-haven-for-hate-groups-report-says.html) criticize the SPLC list, as it contains hate groups which fight against equal rights for LGBT people (such as the Family Research Council; [in their own words](http://www.frc.org/homosexuality), they oppose the idea that gay people should be treated "equivalent to heterosexuality in law").

Note also that the list does not only contain right wing extremists, but all sorts of extremists.

You can look up the location frequency of the particular sort of hate groups you are interested in on their interactive [hate map](https://www.splcenter.org/hate-map).

[CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/08/17/us/hate-groups-us-map-trnd/index.html) made their own map based on the data (it includes all kinds of hate groups):

[image: Map of US with dots indicating "hate" groups]

As is often the case when not correcting for population density, the map can somewhat resemble that of [population density](http://www.capitoltheatreofgreeneville.com/population-density-map-us.html) maps of the US.

Comment: Since California is also the state with the largest population, I'm not sure how useful this information is. California voted heavily democratic, but even a small minority in California can be a large number overall.

Comment: @barrycarter I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Recommend editing the fox news disclaimer regarding the FRC. At current, you're listing as a hate group. Further, there is likely a less objectionable group on the SPLC's that you could referencing. At current, you're poisoning the claim.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I used the Fox article because it's a recent article which is about the number of extremist groups per state, so it fit in with the rest of the answer. And I'm not sure that there are less objectionable groups on the list of hate groups. From what I read, the FRC is the most contested entry (and the Fox article seems to agree; I agree though that it's not really a valid complaint; the FRC is obviously a hate group). if you have sources for other - more contested - entries, I'd be happy to have a look at them.

Comment: Downvoted because the SPLC is far from being an unbiased source.

Comment: @jamesqf I included the criticism of the list. If you have better criticism, please feel free to actually link to it. Just repeating that the SPLC - widely regarded a reliable source -  is biased, without providing any reasons, is not helpful.

Comment: In that the SPLC is biased *against hate groups* sure, but that's what they do. They are experts on hate groups.

Comment: @blip It's their definition of what constitutes a hate group that races concern.

Comment: @DrunkCynic it only raises concern from hate groups. :) But it is fair to say the definition of 'hate group' can be a bit fuzzy.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Could you elaborate on the concern about SPLC's definition of hate groups?

Comment: Looks like the SPLC's definition of "hate group" is intentionally broader than others, where they include groups that don't actively engage in violence.  It's probably worth pointing out this broader definition, but so long as the definition itself isn't misleading and their information's accurate, it seems like a constructive source of information.

Comment: @Nat I don't really see that as broader; no definition of hate group I know of requires violence; advocating hate is enough; and I am unaware of a group on the SPLC's list that wouldn't fit that definition. I don't want to exclude the possibility of valid criticism of the SPLC list (I have seen sensible criticism of individuals the SPLC has named), but all that I have heard up to now regarding hate groups boils down to "my hate is valid, so it shouldn't count" (see the FRC example, which spreads hate against LGBT people, but does not want to be considered a hate group).

Comment: @tim The FBI, by the guidance of the Attorney General, investigates Hate Groups when:"a threat or advocacy of force is made; when the group has the apparent ability to carry out the proclaimed act; and when the act would constitute a potential violation of federal law." The SPLC jointly condemns organizations that act with violence and those that repudiate violence, establishing a false moral equivalency. https://www.fbi.gov/about/faqs/does-the-fbi-investigate-hate-groups-in-the-united-states

Comment: @DrunkCynic The FBI doesn't investigate hate groups that do not engage in physical violence, but it doesn't define hate groups as only those groups that do engage in violence. Using violence as the defining criteria just isn't very reasonable; Even groups like the Institute for Historical Review or the Knights of the Ku Klux Klan would not be categorized as hate groups. Advocating for laws to legalize killing gay people, killing gay people in the streets, or fighting to take basic human rights away from gay people are not the same.But groups which do either should be categorized as hate groups

Comment: @tim if you don't have violence or the promotion of violence in the classification, how do you designate what is a hate group? _Everyone discriminates._

Comment: @Lan Not everyone discriminates, and using violence as your only criteria is just useless nonsense.  [Hate group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hate_group): "A hate group is a social group that advocates and practices hatred, hostility, or violence towards members of a race, ethnicity, nation, religion, gender, gender identity, sexual orientation or any other designated sector of society. [...] The SPLC's definition of a "hate group" includes any group with beliefs or practices that attack or malign an entire class of people—particularly when the characteristics being maligned are immutable."

Comment: SPLC is not a reliable source. It has politicized its list beyond all usefulness, and no serious scholar should ever rely upon it. This article enumerates several complaints against SPLC (http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/reminder-the-southern-poverty-law-center-is-a-fraud-and-nobody-should-treat-them-as-responsible-actors/article/2631852). The Examiner is also not impartial, but the claims and quotes it makes in this editorial are true.

Comment: Also, you should avoid value laden verbiage in your answers. "Fights against equal rights for LGBT people" begs SPLCs and like-minded groups argument. The FRC would certainly not describe its mission that way, and there are less charged ways to describe their position.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove I provided a reliable source as well as criticism of that source. The FRC advocates for jailing gay people (who have sex) and calls gay people pedophiles and a danger to children. For some, that is not a hate group, for others it is. Some would describe it as fighting against equal right, others do not (I added their description). The tabloit you linked to is not reliable, and contains no relevant claims or quotes; it's just namecalling without any evidence or actual arguments. But I'm done with this argument. The facts are all here, and everyone can form their own opinion.

Comment: @tim You think some people don't discriminate? Do you live in a _Brave New World_ where if a person of a gender you aren't attracted to asks for sex, do you give it because you don't discriminate? Everyone has preferences and traits, their mere existence necessitates that others are discriminated.

Comment: The question asks about violence, discrimination based on nationality, and white supremacy. The SPLC's definition of "hate group" is far too broad for the question. The SPLC's definition is not, however broad enough to be consistent with a broad term like "hate" however because only certain kinds of hatred (those the SPLC disagrees with) are on their list.

Comment: @Lan What does that have to do with tim's statement? Not being attracted to people of a certain gender doesn't mean you have to be opposed to those who are.

Comment: @JAB choosing one's sex partners is a very discriminatory act. Excluding an entire group of people from consideration based solely on their gender is that much more so. Attraction is irrelevant and it is a red herring to bring up.

Comment: @Lan "Attraction is irrelevant and it is a red herring to bring up." Then why did you? You seem to be claiming that the fact people are discriminatory in their own sexual choices means being discriminatory about others' sexual choices is just fine, if I've understood correctly.

Comment: @JAB You said " Not being attracted to people of a certain gender doesn't mean you have to be opposed to those who are." Attraction is not the aspect of discrimination I pointed to; it is the discrimination of sexual intercourse.

Comment: @Lan And there is a difference between "I do not want to have sex with that person" and "I do not want that person to have sex with [x]".

Comment: @JAB And that is extremely discriminatory to say you won't have sex with a person. Especially because of their gender. Can you think of anything more discriminatory?

Comment: @Lan you are confusing definition #1 and #2. Either naively (in which case I suggest you look at the two definitions) or on purpose (in which case, that's really lazy trolling) https://www.google.com/search?q=descriminate&oq=descriminate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4246j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

> I'm well aware that there is probably no publicly available data that is really reliable because of the "covert" nature of such groups.

We can try Google Trends for hate group websites.  This provides relative search rates, so population density isn't an issue.

To select a website, I'm going with Stormfront, mostly because they're the hate website that I've heard most about lately:

> Stormfront was a white nationalist,<sup>[4]</sup> white supremacist<sup>[5]</sup> and neo-Nazi<sup>[6]</sup> Internet forum. It was the Web's first major racial hate site.<sup>[7]</sup>
>
> -["Stormfront (website)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormfront_(website)), Wikipedia

The [map](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F03bmkz) from Google Trends:

[image]

And then by subregion:

[image]

Comment: The maps seem...somewhat arbitrary. That said, I spent time in that dark blue spot in WI and there were always stories of KKK history there. So maybe it's spot on.

Comment: Nice idea, but I think that this isn't actually useful. Search rates can have a number of reasons and do not necessarily correlate with hate groups or activities (I mean, do you google stackexchange each time you visit? Most dedicated users already know the URL and visit it directly). People in Vermont might just be more interested in finding out about hate groups, not in participating in their activities.You can also see that in the graph directly. Searches spiked around August, because Stormfront closed; those are likely not searches by hate groups but by people wondering what stormfront was

Comment: Searching for "Stormfront" does not in any way imply that you *agree* with Stormfront.  This could just as easily be interpreted as a map of "people who are so far removed from racism that they've never heard of Stormfront before"